# String behaves weird in rust

Tags: rust

```
let type1 = "Hello";
let mut type2 = String::from("World");
type2.push('!'); //Push can only add one single char
type2.push_str(" from Rust"); // push_str adds a string
let len = type2.len(); //Length of type2
let capacity = type2.capacity(); //Capacity in bytes
let contains = type2.contains("world"); //If contains sub string
println!("{:?}", (type1, type2, len, capacity, contains));

for words in type2.split_whitespace(){
    println!("{}",words);
}
```

This code is giving error but if I remove the print it works just fine

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
println!("{:?}", (type1, type2, len, capacity, contains));
```

You need to change `type2` to `&type2`.

What you find "weird" has nothing to do with strings but the ownership/borrowing model in Rust. If you want to program in Rust, I strongly suggest you don't skip this crucial part of the language. You can start from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html). Also, pay close attention to the compiler error messages. The Rust compiler usually emits incredibly accurate and useful error messages.